# Github AJAX effect efficiently with Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am developing a web application using Laravel. The structure is like Spotify. I don't want to reload the page every time I click in a link or a element, I want to keep the content of the page and just change the main div with the respective content. Also, I want to change the URL so users can access to that page with the link.
I have seen the Github tree-slider, but I have some doubts.

When I click in an element called "song" I will execute the function "showSong" with the respective Laravel route with Ajax, for example "mypage.com/song/1". Then, I will change the URL, so the URL will look like "mypage.com/song/1". The problem is that the function called in Ajax only loads the content of the song, which is fine for Ajax but it's not fine when I access externally from a link.

How could I do it?

Comment: Except by writing all that for you, there's not much way we can help. Please specify a problem, with desired results versus results, something to express what you are doing to solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I would like to be more concrete, but my English is not very good and my problem is how to organize everything, is not just one problem. Sorry for that.

Comment: it's alright :) apply divide and conquer strategy. Start by just reloading a html element with ajax. if that works then go to the next step (sending a song through ajax?) if you have problems along the way you will be able to ask relevant questions. If you are using already existing code you haven't written which you don't understand, this is not the place. We answer specific problems :)

Comment: @souvickcse, re your edit: I think there is a general view here that preformatting is best for code and console i/o. For brands and proper nouns, capital letters are sufficient.

Comment: @halfer still learning the rules thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle AJAX requests differently using `Request::ajax()`:

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
  // do something AJAXy, like present the sound
} else {
  // present a full HTML page, because the user navigated directly to this URL
}
```

You'd use HTML5's state API (most likely with the very handy wrapper [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)) to change the URL when making the AJAX requests.

Comment: I don't know that this answers the question.  He's looking for a way to modify the URL after an AJAX call.

Comment: @user3158900 You're right, I neglected that secondary aspect of things. I added a note about History.js.

Comment: It looks fine, I could show the full view in the not Ajax request and a view of the element in the ajax request. Thank you very much, but I will wait to see if someone has another idea.